# Elasticsearch OR query returns unmatched results

Tags: elasticsearch, nosql

Im trying to use Should to do an OR query, heres my code ..

```
{
    bool: 
        {
            must: [
                {match: { category: "Baby" } }
                ], 
            should: [
                { match: { isPublic: true } },
                { match: { somethingElse: true } }
                ]
        }
}
```

I want it to return results only when one of these should matches occurs, but its returning results where these conditions are not met. How can i make an OR query with similar syntax (im constructing queries dynamically so thats quite important) that will only return results that are both category: "Baby" and EITHER isPublic: true or somethingElse: true?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to add `minimum_should_match: 1`

```
{
    bool: 
        {
            must: [
                {match: { category: "Baby" } }
                ], 
            minimum_should_match: 1,                   <--- add this
            should: [
                { match: { isPublic: true } },
                { match: { somethingElse: true } }
                ]
        }
}
```